# Datagridview not showing up in webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2010 (ASP.NET - C#) and MS SQL Server 2005, and I'm trying to retrieve all the records in my table `tblEmployee` from my database `EMPLOYEES`. There's no error when I debug my program in Visual Studio but when the localhost webpage opens, the datagridview `dgvEmployee` is not there. There are no retrieved records as well. Here's my code:

```
SqlConnection sConn;
SqlDataAdapter daEmp;
DataSet dsEmp;

const string sStr = "Server = Server-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = EMPLOYEES; Integrated Security = SSPI";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sConn = new SqlConnection(sStr);
    daEmp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblEmployee", sConn);
    dsEmp = new DataSet();

    daEmp.Fill(dsEmp, "tblEmployee");

    dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Columns["EmployeeID"] };

    dgvEmployee.DataSource = dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"];
}
```

This is the code in my Defaultpage.aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvEmployee" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

The database and table name is correct, the table have records, and I'm running both programs as Admin. I just can't figure out what's wrong... Is this regarding with the permissions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind the grid, like this:

```
dgvEmployee.DataBind();
```

Note: Unlike Windows development (WinForms, WPF, etc.), the ASP.NET data controls require an explicit call to actually bind the data. On the upside, it is much easier to re-bind to data sources in ASP.NET than Windows development.

---

Another problem you are going to have is that, based upon the markup you posted for your `GridView`, you will not get any data once you actually call `.DataBind()`, because you have no `Columns` defined in your `GridView`.  You can either explicitly define the columns in your markup or set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `True`, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvEmployee" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</asp:GridView>
```

Note: Using the `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` route, will take the exact column names from your data source and use them as headers in your grid; so if you have columns with underscores or abbreviations (i.e. `AVG_COST` or `CUSTOMER_ID`) then they will display exactly like that, with underscores, in your output. This method is useful if you just want to dump the data out into a grid, as is.

To have control over the names of the columns, then you must explicitly define the columns of the grid, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvEmployee" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField datafield="CustomerID" headertext="Customer ID"/>
        <asp:BoundField datafield="CompanyName" headertext="Company Name"/>
        <asp:Boundfield datafield="Address" headertext="Address"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note: Set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` or you will end up with duplicate columns, as it will render your defined columns and then all of the columns in the data source.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. It's working now. Would you also happen to know how to change the header name of the column? This code doesn't seem to be working: `dgvEmployee.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "Employee ID";`

Comment: @user2971155 - see updated answer, sorry I wound up writing a lot more than I thought I would, took some time to update. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use this method after you have given the data source to your grid.

```
dgvEmployee.DataBind()
```

Comment: Please accept this answer if you solved your problem and open another question for the column name issue you are having.